# VueJS access select options inside v-for from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having a firstName and a lastName value inside my state that I need to get from my select to make an API call. But when I try to get the value of the firstName and the lastName independently it is impossible because it is out of the scope of the `v-for`. So I really looked alot for this but I couldn't find much. I need to take the value of the 2 selectors firstName and lastName independently.
Here is my template :

```
<select class="form-select" @change="showValueForTest">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a manager</option>
  <option value="">All the managers</option>
  <option v-for="(manager,index) in managers" :key="manager+index" 
  :value="manager.firstName +' 
 '+ manager.lastName">{{manager.firstName}}{{manager.lastName}} 
 </option>
</select>
```

Here is my method to check if the value even exists , it gives undefined

```
showValueForTest(event){
  console.log(event.target.value.firstName)
}
```

Comment: use `:value="manager"` instead of `:value="manager.firstName +'  '+ manager.lastName"`.

Comment: I get object object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can and `v-model` to select :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      managers: [{firstName: 'aa', lastName: 'bb'}, {firstName: 'cc', lastName: 'dd'}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showValueForTest(){
      console.log(this.selected.firstName)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select class="form-select" v-model="selected" @change="showValueForTest">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a manager</option>
    <option value="">All the managers</option>
    <option v-for="(manager, index) in managers" :key="index" :value="manager">
      {{manager.firstName}}{{manager.lastName}} 
    </option>  
  </select>
</div>
```